# nftables named sets that match network prefixes though filter or variables

Tags: nftables

I want to match a set of networks.
Anonymous sets works fine, but I want to create prefix set to reuse it when needed.

```
nft add set filter AllowedSSH { type ipv4_addr\;} // type for addreses
nft add element filter AllowedSSH { 10.0.0.0/8 } // not working
nft add element filter AllowedSSH { 10.0.0.1 } // works by IP
```

What correct type of filter I should use to perform this action?

Variables style don't work too:

```
nft define networks = { 10.0.0.0/8 }
nft add rule ip filter input ip saddr $networks tcp dport 22 accept
Error: syntax error, unexpected dport, expecting end of file or newline or semicolon
add rule ip filter input ip saddr tcp dport 53 counter accept
                                  ^^^^^
```

NFT version:

```
[root@foo ~]# nft -v
nftables v0.8 (Joe Btfsplk)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want add the prefixes into the set, you should specify the `interval` flag.

In your example it will be look like:

```
nft add set filter AllowedSSH { type ipv4_addr\; flags interval\; }
nft add element filter AllowedSSH { 10.0.0.0/8 }
nft add element filter AllowedSSH { 192.168.0.0/24 }

nft list set filter AllowedSSH
table ip filter {
    set AllowedSSH {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/24 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? I already despaired. Thanks for working example!!!